# Splitting a list in non-equal width chunks in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, scale, logarithm

I am trying to do something like in Haskell:

```
mkList start end nb_chunck will output [start, boun1, bound2, bound3 ..., end]
```

However I don't want to split the list in equal-size chunk but to follow a logarithmic scale.

The C algorithm I want to transform in Haskell is availabke here: [How to get a logarithmic distribution from an interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585913/how-to-get-a-logarithmic-distribution-from-an-interval)

I don't really know how to do it.

Here's what I have attempted so far:

```
mkList :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
mkList _ _ _ _ 7 = []
mkList lower upper start end n = [lower, ((fromIntegral (log(2 + (fromIntegral n :: Int)) )+start) * scale)] ++ (mkList (fromIntegral(((fromIntegral (log(2 + (fromIntegral n :: Int)) )+start) * scale)+1) :: Int) ((fromIntegral (log(2 + (fromIntegral (n) :: Int)) )+start) * scale) (start) end (fromIntegral (n+1) :: Int)) where
scale = (end - start) `quot` floor(log(1 + (6)))
```

However, I can't validate this code, because when I compile, error messages pop up:

```
haskell_par3.hs:71:58:
No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of `log'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
In the first argument of `fromIntegral', namely
  `(log (2 + (fromIntegral n :: Int)))'
In the first argument of `(+)', namely
  `fromIntegral (log (2 + (fromIntegral n :: Int)))'
In the first argument of `(*)', namely
  `(fromIntegral (log (2 + (fromIntegral n :: Int))) + start)'
ghc -cpp: /usr/hs/ghc/7.6.3/bin/ghc failure (return code=1)
```

I've tried to make use of `fromIntegral` at different spots but it didn't help, as seen in other answered questions on StackOverflow.

So I'm asking two things:

- Do you have any precise idea of how I could fix these compilation errors? (I know it has something to do with `fromIntegral`, but I can't get rid of this error).
- And more important: Do you think this code may achieve what I want to do? If no, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: About your compilation error, didn't you ask the same thing [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142846/conversion-between-int-and-fractional-values-splitting-an-interval-following-a)?

Comment: It is probably related. However I have edited my question to indicate that I have tried to use `fromIntegral` at different locations in my code to solve my problem. But it didn't work. So that's one of the reason why I have created a new question.

Comment: `fromIntegral` does not work on results of `log`, and `(fromIntegral n :: Int)` won't change the type at all (you meant `fromIntegral (n :: Int)`. You should probably read a tutorial about the numeric types and the proper conversion between them.

Comment: Yes, but I can't see it in my asked questions (and probably other people can't too) on this forum and I assumed it was because, the question had been labelled to another answered question on this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this to create a log scale intervals

```
scale k n = map (floor . (*k) . (/(log n)) . log) [1..n]
```

e.g.

```
scale 100 9
[0,31,50,63,73,81,88,94,100]
```

and use the indices to partition the array by start/end indices.

You can cast the output to [Int] since floor convert it to an Integral type

```
Prelude> scale 10 3 :: [Int]
[0,6,10]
Prelude> :t it
it :: [Int]
```

Comment: `n` is an `Int`, which is part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You solved my main query